# Click event not working properly in cefsharp browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, cefsharp

I am working with Charts rendered as SVG elements using jQuery in cefsharp browser. I have bind click event to whole SVG element, in that I have append various SVG shapes.

And my question is if I render two shapes in a same place click event is not fired. But if I click on other region it is working fine. Have a look at the below image.
[image]

And my DOM structure is
[image]

The highlighted elements are the circles which got rendered and displayed in first screen shot.

Guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Report it as a bug to the cefsharp bugtracker assuming it has one.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-cef

Comment: Also how does this behave in `Chrome`? Also you need to include what version of `CefSharp` your using, eg. `41.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Me and a friend had a similar problem, we could get the javascript (jQuery) code working in any browser console, but we could not fire the click event in cefsharp.

This works in console, but not in cefsharp:

`$('.fancy_button').trigger('click');`

But, bubbling does the trick. No idea why, but fire the click event on a child element works, it bubbles up to the parent element, and somehow this works in cefsharp:

`$('.fancy_button').find('span').trigger('click');`

Hope this helps someone.